# Select in PL-SQL Errors: INTO After Select

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, plsql

I've the following query in a **test script window**

```
declare
  -- Local variables here
  p_StartDate date := to_date('10/15/2012');
  p_EndDate   date := to_date('10/16/2012');
  p_ClientID  integer := 000192;
begin
  -- Test statements here
  select d.r                          "R",
         e.amount                     "Amount",
         e.inv_da                     "InvoiceData",
         e.product                    "ProductId",
         d.system_time                "Date",
         d.action_code                "Status",
         e.term_rrn                   "IRRN",
         d.commiount                  "Commission",
         0                            "CardStatus"
    from docs d
   inner join ext_inv e on d.id = e.or_document
   inner join term t on t.id = d.term_id
   where d.system_time >= p_StartDate
     and d.system_time <= p_EndDate
     and e.need_r = 1
     and t.term_gr_id = p_ClientID;
end
```

Here is the **error**:

> ORA-06550: line 9, column 3: PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

I've been using T-SQL for a long time and I'm new to PL/SQL.

What's wrong here?

Comment: What would you expect? The resultset of the query as the output of your block? PL/SQL doesn't work like that...

Comment: I just want to see selected data...

Comment: @levi :your using toad or pl sql developer ?

Comment: @levi, If all you want is to view the data you don't really need plsql - you can open a `sql window` and run your select

Comment: @A.B.Cade but there are decalring and as I know it can't be in sql window. There is error in sql window too

Answer (score 0):

These columns need to be stored in some type structure.
like given in this example

```
DECLARE
  deptid        employees.department_id%TYPE;
  jobid         employees.job_id%TYPE;
  emp_rec       employees%ROWTYPE;
**Create type structure**
  TYPE emp_tab IS TABLE OF employees%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  all_emps      emp_tab;
BEGIN
  SELECT department_id, job_id INTO deptid, jobid 
     FROM employees WHERE employee_id = 140;
  IF SQL%FOUND THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Dept Id: ' || deptid || ', Job Id: ' || jobid);
  END IF;
  SELECT * INTO emp_rec FROM employees WHERE employee_id = 105;
  SELECT * INTO all_emps FROM employees;  **//storing into all_emp type structure**
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of rows: ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you really want is quering the db with some parameters, then you have some options:
1- use sqlplus or plsql developer "command window" or "sql window" with the query like this:

```
  select d.r                          "R",
         e.amount                     "Amount",
         e.inv_da                     "InvoiceData",
         e.product                    "ProductId",
         d.system_time                "Date",
         d.action_code                "Status",
         e.term_rrn                   "IRRN",
         d.commiount                  "Commission",
         0                            "CardStatus"
    from docs d
   inner join ext_inv e on d.id = e.or_document
   inner join term t on t.id = d.term_id
   where d.system_time >= &p_StartDate
     and d.system_time <= &p_EndDate
     and e.need_r = 1
     and t.term_gr_id = &p_ClientID;
```

You'll be prompted to give values to the parameters.

2- You can use plsql (though I don't see why) but then you need an explicit cursor
For example if you're using a "test window":

```
declare
  -- Local variables here
  p_StartDate date := to_date('10/15/2012');
  p_EndDate   date := to_date('10/16/2012');
  p_ClientID  integer := 000192;
begin
  -- Test statements here
  OPEN :src FOR select d.r                          "R",
         e.amount                     "Amount",
         e.inv_da                     "InvoiceData",
         e.product                    "ProductId",
         d.system_time                "Date",
         d.action_code                "Status",
         e.term_rrn                   "IRRN",
         d.commiount                  "Commission",
         0                            "CardStatus"
    from docs d
   inner join ext_inv e on d.id = e.or_document
   inner join term t on t.id = d.term_id
   where d.system_time >= p_StartDate
     and d.system_time <= p_EndDate
     and e.need_r = 1
     and t.term_gr_id = p_ClientID;
end
```

Note that you need to add a variable in the table below with the name "src" and type "cursor", after running the plsql block it will hold the resultset

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  -- Local variables here
  p_StartDate date := to_date('10/15/2012');
  p_EndDate   date := to_date('10/16/2012');
  p_ClientID  integer := 000192;
begin
  for cur in ( select d.r                          "R",
                      e.amount                     "Amount",
                      e.inv_da                     "InvoiceData",
                      e.product                    "ProductId",
                      d.system_time                "Date",
                      d.action_code                "Status",
                      e.term_rrn                   "IRRN",
                      d.commiount                  "Commission",
                      0                            "CardStatus"
                 from docs d
                 inner join ext_inv e on d.id = e.or_document
                 inner join term t on t.id = d.term_id
                 where d.system_time >= p_StartDate
                   and d.system_time <= p_EndDate
                   and e.need_r = 1
                   and t.term_gr_id = p_ClientID)
   LOOP
       dbms_output.put_line('R: '||cur.R||'Amount:  '||cur.Amount/*...*/);
   END LOOP;

end;
/
```