# Oracle: Declare multiple constants and use them in WHERE clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

I perform daily extractions from the same table. The only thing that ever changes is the range of a column called `SAMPLE_ID`, so I would like to assign a fixed value to two variables: `id_min` and `id_max` so that I can update their values before running the query.

I tried the following:

```sql
DECLARE
    id_min  CONSTANT INTEGER := 17778;
    id_max  CONSTANT INTEGER := 17803;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        MDB.SCORES
    WHERE
        SAMPLE_ID BETWEEN id_min AND id_max;
END;
```

I expected this code to use the numbers assigned to `id_min` and `id_max` as the lower and upper bounds of the `BETWEEN` function in the `WHERE` clause, but I'm getting this message:

```
ORA-06550: line 6, column 5:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

It seems someone ran into something similar in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911452/select-in-pl-sql-errors-into-after-select), but I do not understand the solutions provided.

Comment: You need to store the result of the select somewhere. You can't just write a SELECT statement like that in PL/SQL. See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520375/how-do-i-return-a-set-of-results-from-a-query-window-in-oracle-sql-developer/34522760#34522760

Comment: Oh, I see. So PL/SQL is expecting me to write the query result into a table?

Comment: Or return it as shown in the answer I linked to.

Comment: PL/SQL is a programming language, not a query language. It’s expecting you to process the results somehow. It can’t just process an implicit cursor and not do anything with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not realize `DECLARE` would require `PL/SQL`. I found it easier to do the following using `DEFINE`.

```sql
DEFINE id_min = 17778
DEFINE id_max = 17803;

SELECT
    *
FROM
    MDB.SCORES
WHERE
    SAMPLE_ID BETWEEN &id_min AND &id_max;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are running a PL/SQL code, you cannot just run a SELECT query without doing something with it.

There are some ways on dealing with select queries in PL/SQL.

1) `INTO` clause, where you take the row returned from the query and assign them to variables. *Notice is said row, not rows. If your query returns more then one row you cannot use `INTO` clause since it will generate `TO_MANY_ROWS` exception.

```
DECLARE
    id_min  CONSTANT INTEGER := 17778;
    id_max  CONSTANT INTEGER := 17803;
    variable1 your_variable_type;
    variable2 your_variable_type;
    variable3 your_variable_type;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        *
    INTO
        variable1,
        variable2,
        variable3
    FROM
        MDB.SCORES
    WHERE
        SAMPLE_ID BETWEEN id_min AND id_max;

    ---- DO SOMETHING WITH YOUR VARIABLES ----    
END;
```

2) `FOR` loop if you have one or many rows.

```
DECLARE
    id_min  CONSTANT INTEGER := 17778;
    id_max  CONSTANT INTEGER := 17803;
BEGIN

    FOR c IN (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            MDB.SCORES
        WHERE
            SAMPLE_ID BETWEEN id_min AND id_max
    ) LOOP
        ---- DO SOMETHING WITH YOUR VARIABLES ----  
        ---- ACCESS A COLUMN ----

        c.column_name;

    END LOOP;
END;
```

3) `CURSOR` declaring.

```
DECLARE
    id_min  CONSTANT INTEGER := 17778;
    id_max  CONSTANT INTEGER := 17803;
    v_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    your_variables
    ...
BEGIN

    OPEN v_cursor FOR
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            MDB.SCORES
        WHERE
            SAMPLE_ID BETWEEN id_min AND id_max;
    LOOP
        FETCH v_cursor INTO your_variables;
        EXIT WHEN v_cursor%NOTFOUND;

        ---- DO SOMETHING WITH YOUR VARIABLES ----  

    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: For option 3 "cursor declaring", a good "do something with your variables" might be `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(v_cursor)`, since the OP seems to be trying to run the PL/SQL block as though it were a query.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are between BEGIN and END you are no longer in SQL, but in PLSQL.

In PL/SQL there is no just select statement, there is a "select ... INTO ..." statement instead.

In other words, the database wants from you a variable to save the results to.

Or you might use a loop in order to operate with data.
Below is the loop example to print the data from some_column out

```
DECLARE
     id_min  CONSTANT INTEGER := 17778;
    id_max  CONSTANT INTEGER := 17803;
BEGIN
  for score in (SELECT *
                  FROM MDB.SCORES
                 WHERE SAMPLE_ID BETWEEN id_min AND id_max) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(sc.some_column_name);
  end loop;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find it simpler to [use bind variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564283/how-to-declare-variable-and-use-it-in-the-same-oracle-sql-script), and not run your query in PL/SQL at all.

```
var id_min NUMBER
var id_max NUMBER

begin
  :id_min := 17778;
  :id_max := 17803;
end;
/

SELECT
    *
FROM
    MDB.SCORES
WHERE
    SAMPLE_ID BETWEEN :id_min AND :id_max;
```